# jqmobi(appframework): how to use CSS style "position:fixed"?

Tags: jqmobi, appframework

I use CSS style "position:fixed" in jqmobi, but it dosen't works!

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="afui">
    <div id="header">Test</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="index" class="panel">
            <div style="position:fixed;">It dosen't works!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Somebody help me? Thanks!